# compatibility of microsoft botframework-v4

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I have a concern whether bots created using Microsoft bot framework v4 is compatible in teams or not.
I have uploaded my manifest in teams yet I'm not receiving any reply from bot where i used to get replies from the bot created using v3 version

Comment: Could you please share bot id for which you are getting this issue? Could you please also confirm that Microsoft Teams is added as channel in your bot?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes I have added teams as channel. This is the documentation that is making me doubt the compatibility of bot in teams https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/preview-release-of-net-teams-bot-builder-v4-sdk/

Comment: V3 bots are very compatible with Teams and I believe most, if not all, features work. Does your bot work locally? If you can include your bot code, I can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Both v3 and v4 bots are supported in Microsoft Teams. However, the Teams Bot Builder SDK v4 is still in beta, which is what the blog post is refering to. However, your bot not responding from MS Teams is unlikely to be caused by an SDK version conflict.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT im not facing any issue with my v3 bot but with my v4 bot . Thanks for you help .

Comment: @AndrewClear so what you are saying is that Teams Bot Builder SDK V4 is not production ready ..Thanks as it will save a lot of time for me from trying.

Comment: @ElmaSarahDaniel Sorry. I meant to say V4. Both V3 and V4 are compatible with Teams. I've built several V4 Teams bots that have used quite a few different features and they all worked. Regarding Andrew's comment, Teams has their own Teams Bot Builder SDK that is in beta for V4 (it's basically a wrapper that makes some of the Teams-specific stuff easier). You don't need it, though. You can build a regular bot without it, using the standard BotBuilder SDK V4, and it still works just fine with Teams.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT thanks .. this will help me as well other developers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V4 bots are very compatible with Teams and I believe most, if not all, features work. I've built several V4 Teams bots that have used quite a few different features and they all worked. Regarding Andrew's comment, Teams has their own Teams Bot Builder SDK that is in beta for V4 (it's basically a wrapper that makes some of the Teams-specific stuff easier). You don't need it, though. You can build a regular bot without it, using the standard BotBuilder SDK V4, and it still works just fine with Teams.

Comment: You can find links to the Teams Bot Builder SDKs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/#pivot=sdk-tools